# Dynamically append column to table row with unique ID

Tags: jquery

I have a below table, where I want to append a columns named name3 with radio buttons. I have a dropdown, based on the selection value columns should be appended.

```
             name1             name2

    meal1    radiobutton       radiobutton
    meal2    radiobutton       radiobutton

<tr class="details">
   <th width="40%">&nbsp;</th>
   <th width="25%">name1</th>
                            
</tr>
<tr class="mealsSelection">
   <td width="40%">meal1</td>
   <td width="25%" align="center">
   <div class="custom-radiobtn-wrap">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mr-1">
   <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline{{$i}}" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
   <label class="custom-control-label" style="text-indent: -9999999px; height: 32px; width:0;"
          for="customRadioInline{{$i}}"></label>
   </div>
   </div>
</tr>
```

In my script I am appending a new column to mealsSelection class using the following code. On change of a dropdown I need to append the columns. If I select 2 from dropdown 2 columns should be appended.

```
$('#guestnumber').change(function (e) {
    var guestNo = $("#guestnumber").val();
    
    if (guestNo) {
        for (var gNo = 1; gNo <= guestNo; gNo++) {
            var loop1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90 + 10);
            appendColumnForGuest(loop1,gNo);
        }
    }

});

function appendColumnForGuest(loop1,gNo) {
    var i = loop1;
    var j = loop1;
    $('#selectmeals tr.details').append('<th width="35%" class="text-left">Guest '+gNo+'</th>')
    $('#selectmeals tr.mealsSelection').append(
        '<td width="35%" align="left">' +
        '<div class="custom-radiobtn-wrap ml-3">' +
        '<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline mr-1">' +
        '<input type="radio" id="customRadioInline" name="customRadioInline2" class="'+loop1+'appendedradio custom-control-input">' +
        '<label class="'+loop1+'appendedlabel custom-control-label" style="text-indent: -9999999px; height: 32px; width:0;" for="customRadioInline"></label>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'

    );

    $('.'+loop1+'appendedlabel').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('for', "customRadioInline" + i);
        i++;
    });
    $('.'+loop1+'appendedradio').each(function () {

        $(this).attr('id', "customRadioInline" + j);
        j++;
    });
}
```

Here when I select 2 from dropdown I get 2 columns. When I click a radio button from 1st appended column it will be selected. But when I click a radio button from the 2nd appended column the 1st selection will be removed.
I want to select a radio button from each appended column. How can I change the function like that.

Comment: Hi how you are appending new columns ? Onlick of some button where is that button?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: @Oops try set `name` of radio button different for each in your code.

Comment: yes yes .. I thought I already set the name different for each column, but I didn't. Thank you for pointing out :)

Comment: @Oops I hope it helps, If you want selection across  same column them all radio button in same column with same name. Otherwise all radio in each `cell` with different name is no point, Instead use Checkbox

Comment: @yogendarji Yes it helped Yogen. Thank you :)